# Object created in main doesnt perform in other classess

Tags: java, class, object, multiple-inheritance

I need help. Im stuck with this.

This is the class restaurant. I want to use my objects wtr1,wtr2,wtr3 that are of waiters class.I initiated them in my main.

```
public class restaurant extends player{
private final waiters wtr1 , wtr2 ,wtr3;




public restaurant(waiters wt1 ,waiters wt2 , waiters wt3 )
    {

        super();
    this.wtr1=wt1;
    this.wtr2=wt2;
    this.wtr3=wt3;


public float calculateSalary()
    {
        employee emp = new employee();

        float wtrsal1 = 0;
        float wtrsal2 = 0;
        float wtrsal3 = 0;
        float sal=0;

        switch (wtr1.wExp)
        {
        case "low":

            wtrsal1 = emp.salarywaiter[0];
            break;

        case "medium":

            wtrsal1 = emp.salarywaiter[1];
            break;

        case "high":

            wtrsal1 = emp.salarywaiter[2];
            break;


        }



        switch (wtr2.wExp)
        {
        case "low":

            wtrsal2 = emp.salarywaiter[0];
            break;

        case "medium":

            wtrsal2 = emp.salarywaiter[1];
            break;

        case "high":

            wtrsal2 = emp.salarywaiter[2];
            break;

        }



        switch (wtr3.wExp)
        {
        case "low":

            wtrsal3 = emp.salarywaiter[0];
            break;

        case "medium":

            wtrsal3 = emp.salarywaiter[1];
            break;

        case "high":

            wtrsal3 = emp.salarywaiter[2];
            break;

        }


        sal = wtrsal1 + wtrsal2 + wtrsal3;

        return sal;


        }
```

And this is my main.I dont know if in the arguments for rest should be nulls,but it was set by default.Program doesnt excecute,it gives me error that wt1.wExp is wrong and that `System.out.println(rest.calculateSalary());` is wrong.

```
waiters wt1 = new waiters (19 , 0 );
        waiters wt2 = new waiters(20 , 0 );
        waiters wt3 = new waiters (21 , 0);
        restaurant rest= new restaurant(null, null, null);
        System.out.println(rest.calculateSalary());
```

Here is the waiters class:

```
public class waiters extends employee {


    String wname;
    String wsurname;
    String wExp;


    public waiters(int i , int n )
    {
         wname = getname(i);
         wsurname = getsurname(i);
         wExp = ExpirienceLevel[n];
    }



}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this multiple-inheritance? I see nothing about multiple inheritance in the question. Additionally, you should really look up Java naming conventions and pay more attention to indentation/formatting. The easier you can make it to read your code, the better - both for others and for you. It would also help if you'd post a short but *complete* example, rather than snippets here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Chit:

```
restaurant rest= new restaurant(null, null, null);
```

You're not passing in the Waiters that you've created but rather are only passing in nulls, so what do you expect will happen? The restaurant instance will only hold `null` references and will not magically be able to use the waiter objects. **You** have to pass them in -- If you want restaurant to use the Waiter references, pass them in via the constructor.

```
 waiters wt1 = new waiters (19 , 0 );
 waiters wt2 = new waiters(20 , 0 );
 waiters wt3 = new waiters (21 , 0);
 restaurant rest= new restaurant(wt1, wt2, wt3);
 System.out.println(rest.calculateSalary());
```

Comment: yeah,but what value should i pass,whatever i put it gives me error?

Comment: @vulovicv: you pass in the Waiter objects that you've just created -- see edit to answer. You will want to read the tutorials on creating and calling methods and constructors.

Comment: @vulovicv: again, read the tutorials on this because this is foundational material. You need to understand this well if you're going to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
restaurant rest= new restaurant(null, null, null);
```

you're creating your restaurant, but the waiters you created are not being sent to the restaurant! You've used three `null` waiters. You just needed

```
restaurant rest= new restaurant(wtr1, wtr2, wtr3);
```

You mentioned that the `null`s were put there automatically. When your IDE creates the outline for the method call for you, it might populate with allowable default values, depending on how it's configured. For object references, it'll default to giving you `null`s, because there's really nothing else it knows how to put in there for you. Don't assume that automatically generated code is correct!